# Ethereum wallet shows "no accounts yet" and 0.00 balance

Tags: mist, synchronization, accounts, ethereum-wallet-dapp, balances

I last used Ethereum wallet in June or July this year. Yesterday I upgraded on macOS to 0.8.7. It is syncing very slowly; at this rate it will take a week to finish the remaining 189,000 blocks.

In the meantime I see the disturbing Message "You have no accounts yet" and it shows a balance of 0.00 Ether.

Is it possible I have to wait for sync to see my account reappear and my balance show up?

If that's not what's happening, what files on macOS should I look at, or recover if lost?

To be clear, this isn't an issue of losing a password. I just see "no accounts yet" and zero balance.